# List of folders being synchronised on Ubuntu One

Tags: ubuntu-one, backup, sync

I think Ubuntu One is syncing my backup folder (deja-dup).  I'm concerned this could be a problem should a file become corrupted, and I need to retrieve it.  Is there some way I can see a list of synced folders and turn off ones I do not want? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

To view the folders Ubuntu One is syncing you need to open the Ubuntu One Control Panel. The first view you come across will be the list of folders currently being synchronised.

[image]

If you see you deja-dup backup folder in there and you want to stop it syncing, then you can do one of two things.

1. Uncheck the "Sync locally" option in the Ubuntu One Control Panel. This will not remove the folder from Ubuntu One, but it will stop any further changes being synced.
2. If you want to remove it completely from Ubuntu One, the you need to go to the web view at [one.ubuntu.com](https://one.ubuntu.com/dashboard/). Log in and select the "Files" tab to view the list of files and folders stored in Ubuntu One. Find your backup folder and click on the "More" link on the right-hand side. This will reveal an option to "Stop synchronising this folder". Clicking that will remove your backup folder from Ubuntu One entirely. Both of these options are marked in red below.

[image]